# What are equivalents of 10K and 10Q in India

Tags: united-states, stocks, india, annual-report, quarterly-report

According to [investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/1/10-k.asp):

> A 10-K is a comprehensive report filed annually by a publicly-traded company about its financial performance and is required by the U.S. Securities and Exchange Commission (SEC). The report contains much more detail than a company's annual report

[and](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/1/10q.asp):

> SEC Form 10-Q is a comprehensive report of financial performance that must be submitted quarterly by all public companies to the Securities and Exchange Commission (SEC). In the 10-Q, firms are required to disclose relevant information regarding their finances as a result of their business operations. The 10-Q is generally an unaudited report.

For example, [this](https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/0001018724/000101872421000004/amzn-20201231.htm) is Amazon's 10K report and [this](https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/0001018724/000101872421000010/amzn-20210331.htm) is Amazon's 10Q report.

I want to know if something similar (annual and quarterly annual reports in HTML format) is available for Indian stock exchanges?

I mainly want official textual information of the company, its current affairs. (Official means the one provided by the company itself)